# Trying to show the max temperature of a city from a text file but Im having all cities and temperatures

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

Im trying to develop a mapreduce program to show the city with max temperature from a text file.

The text file "temperatures.txt" have this content (city and temperature):

City1 10

City2 11

City3 4

City4 20

...

city10000 22

In this example, the result I want is to print this last line, that have higher temperature:

city10000 22

I have the reducer file like this:

```
import sys

current_city = None
current_max = 0
city = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    city, temperature = line.rsplit('\t', 1)

    try:
        temperature = float(temperature)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if current_city == city:
        if temperature > current_max:
            current_max = temperature
    else:
        if current_city:
            print '%s\t%s' % (current_city, current_max)
        current_max = temperature
        current_city = city

if current_city == city:
    print '%s\t%s' % (current_city, current_max)
```

But, when I test this reducer.py file, Im having always the same result, Im getting always all cities and temperatures, like this:

City1 10

City2 11

City3 4

City4 20

...

city10000 22

Do you see anything wrong in my reducer file?

I just want to show the city with max temperature, in this case city with max temperature is city10000, so I want only this result:

city10000 22

Comment: am a bit tired, but I think the problem is within the `if current_city == city, else:` part, because if the city is not `current_city`, then you just take the temperature and assign it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let me explain where I believe the code has gone wrong and then I will supply a working example. The problem is with the if else statement in the reducer.

Here is the if part:

```
if current_city == city:
    if temperature > current_max:
        current_max = temperature
```

This will only happen if the same city is listed twice, more **importantly** this is the only place where the code checks if the `temperature` of the new city is bigger than the `current_max`.

I suspect most of the time will be spent in the `else` part of the statement:

```
else:
    if current_city:
        print '%s\t%s' % (current_city, current_max)
    current_max = temperature
    current_city = city
```

There are two problems here:

1. The program will always print a line when `current_city` is defined. This is what is producing your list of cities from the reducer.
2. The program also assists the `current_max` variable without check if `temperature` is bigger.

Here is a reducer that should work:

```
import sys

current_city = None
current_max = 0
city = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    city, temperature = line.rsplit('\t', 1)

    try:
        temperature = float(temperature)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if temperature > current_max:
        current_max = temperature
        current_city = city

print '%s\t%s' % (current_city, current_max)
```

The last thing I would mention is that it is not a good idea setting `current_max = 0`. Temperatures in celsius can easily be below zero. If your list of cities and temperature were during winter, there is a possibility that none of them had a temperature over 0 and the code would return:

```
None    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was really what you mentioned, now its working.

Comment: By the way, do you see how can I change the reducer file to show the 5 cities with higher temperatures?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about python. But you can follow below scenario:

-> create a map to store key as city and value as temperature.

-> Now, store first five cities with their temperature in map.

-> After 5 cities, compare the temperature of each city with all 5 cities in map. If temperature of any city in the map is less then replace that city and their temperature with new city.

-> At the end, You can print the map. This will get the 5 cities with maximum temperature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The maper is already working fine. The only issue is with reducer file, because its showing all cities that I have in text file and I just want the city with max temperature. For now for testing, Im just trying to have the city with max temperature and then the 5 cities with max temperature

Comment: can i give you java code...for the same? so you can relate with python

Comment: With "map" he does not mean the mapper, but still your reducer. He just wants to refer to a python "dictionary" (in Java and probably some other languages these are called maps). So the idea is yo create a dict in your reducer with the 5 highest temps + cities and always maintain this up to date.

Comment: map in java means we are storing 5 cities in HashMap

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In your example you are using mapreduce? I dont know if we are talking about the same thing..

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

 public class Weather {

  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         String line = value.toString();
           String year = line.substring(15, 19);

           int airTemperature;
           if (line.charAt(87) == '+') {
                        airTemperature= Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
                    }
           else
               airTemperature= - Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));

                if(airTemperature!=9999 && airTemperature!=-9999){
                    airTemperature/=10;
                context.write(new Text(year),new IntWritable(airTemperature));
                }
       }
  } 

  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
       throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         int maxValue=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

         Iterator<IntWritable> itr = values.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()){
             maxValue = Math.max(maxValue,itr.next().get());
         }
         context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();

         Job job = new Job(conf, "temparature");
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
     job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);  

     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/input/"));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/output/"));

     // FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    //  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

     job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }

 }
```

Dataset of Weather data:

0029029070999991901010106004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0202701N015919999999N0000001N9-00781+99999102001ADDGF108991999999999999999999

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont know much about java, but Im trying to adapt the code to python to see if it works!

Comment: Again, thanks for your help, but I didnt have sucess adapting your java code!